# How to use tsconfig path aliases in a frontend React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, tsconfig

I want to setup the paths config in my create-react-app React frontend project `mylib`.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@bla/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Here's how my project's folders look:

```
mylib
-build
-src
--stuff
---things
----x.js
```

This project is a custom library that I compile using Babel, and that I `npm link` to test it in another React project, `myproject`.
Here's the top of the `myFile.tsx` file in `myproject`:

```
import * as myImport from '@bla/stuff/things/x'
```

Here's the output:

> Failed to compile.
> ../myproject/build/stuff/things/myFile.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@bla/stuff/things/x' in
> 'C:\Users\xxx\myproject\build\folderInWhichMyFileIs'

What am I missing here?

I have found other related SO questions, but people are saying to use the `module-alias` library, which only works for backend code. I'm also not using `ts-node`.

Comment: I would encourage you to get away from using `create-react-app` as it is now deprecated.  Consider moving to something like Vite, which automatically sets up a lot of this type of useful configuration for you.

Comment: @GregFenton This is not a new project, it's an older 2019 app, unfortunately!

Comment: It isn't a lot of work to convert.  I have done it several times.  Sure is easier to work with maintained toolkit than continuing to tweak a deprecated one :)

Comment: While I 100% agree with you on the principle, the decision isn't mine to make :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically set up path aliases to simplify imports. This can make your project's directory structure cleaner and easier to manage.

the `tsconfig` must be in the project root, and then you can use the folder structure like this, if the folder has subfolder you need to include it

```json
// This does't work ❌
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
     //...
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "twin.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
}
```

```json
// This should work ✅
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
     //...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "twin.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

Comment: I already do that, like I said in my question. I know what path aliases are for, I'm asking how to make them work (:

Comment: @Eva then I think you have another issue: the typescript compiler is not working!

Comment: @Eva please check the solution now

Comment: Hello, as stated in the question, `paths` already is inside `compilerOptions`. Is there something else I should be doing? Are those `include` and `exclude` relevant somehow?